# How to declare a variable inside nested structure?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a nested structure with objects and functions in JavaScript as shown below:

```
this.x = {
   f1: function() {
   },
   f2: function() {
   },
   nested: {
      f3: function() {
      },
      f4: function() {
      }
   }
}
```

Suppose I want to declare a variable that is only known to to functions f3 and f4. Where and how would I declare this variable?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this?

```
this.x = {
   f1: function() {
   },
   f2: function() {
   },
   nested: (function() {
      var nested_var;
      return {
          f3: function() {
              // nested_var in scope here
          },
          f4: function() {
              // and here, shared between f3 and f4
          }
      }; 
   })();
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to call `nested` immediately?

Answer (score 1):

From your structure, it looks like nested is supposed to be an object, correct?  You can use what is called a self executing function.

```
x = {
  f1: function() {
      //Does not have access to abc
  }, 
  f2: function() {
      //Does not have access to abc
  }
};
x.nested = (function() {
  var abc = '123';
  //Must return an object here to keep nested as an object
  return {
    f3: function() {
      console.log(abc);
    }, 
    f4: function() {
        console.log(abc);
    }
  };
})();
```

Functions contained within `x.nested` will be able to access `abc` as if it were a global variable shared between each other while `f1` and `f2` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the variable inside the scope of the function and it will only be visible to that function. Ex.

```
function f3() {
  var nestedVar = 3;
}

var notNested = nestedVar;   // this will not work
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this:

```
this.x = {
   f1: function() {
   },
   f2: function() {
   },
   nested: (function(){
     var priv=0;
     return {
       f3:function(){priv++;},
       f4:function(){return priv;}
     };
   })()
};
```

The `(function(){/*code*/})()` section is an anonymous function that is then executed (you'll sometimes see these in userscripts and bookmarklets).